# How to use rescue_from for an array of errors with splat operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to catch an array of errors from my ActiveJob's perform method using `rescue_from`. I've been using the splat operator and `rescue` like this:

```
ERRORS = [
  CustomErrorA,
  CustomErrorB,
  # ...
].freeze

def perform()
  # implementation
rescue *ERRORS => e
  handle_error(e)
end
```

And I would like to do something like:

```
rescue_from(*ERRORS, with: :handle_error)

# or alternatively

rescue_from *ERRORS do |e|
  handle_error(e)
end
```

Is it possible to use the splat operator this way? Or do I have to keep the `rescue` block in order to catch all errors in the array? Is there any better way I'm not aware of?

Comment: I don't think you can splat a rescue list. Maybe it is a design problem: If the errors are related, why not having them inherited from a common base class, and rescue the base class?

Comment: That could work I guess, could you write this solution as an answer?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your original problem, just a basic principle of OOP, so I'm a bit reluctant to write it as a _solution_.

Comment: You could always go for a "not possible, do this instead" solution. I agree is not a direct solution to the question itself but it is to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`rescue_from` associates the handler with the exception class, but it still has to be called with `rescue_with_handler`, so the implementation would be:

```rb
require 'active_support/rescuable'

class Test
  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable

  class CustomErrorA < StandardError; end
  class CustomErrorB < StandardError; end

  ERRORS = [CustomErrorA, CustomErrorB]

  rescue_from *ERRORS, with: :handle_error

  def handle_error
    puts "something is borked"
  end

  def rescue_test
    raise Test::CustomErrorA
  rescue *ERRORS => e
    rescue_with_handler e
  end

end

tt = Test.new
tt.rescue_test
```

It works, but it doesn't really buy you anything over what you are already using.